# How do you pass data from an public Shopify API to their liquid templates

Tags: shopify, liquid

I completed the QRCode test application on Shopify, which was easy to go through and very well done. Now that I have it up I can't seem to figure out how to dynamically add the QR code to a page in the liquid template. The proxy URL throws a CORS error when hit with JS (which I'm guessing is on purpose by Shopify). I can hit the end points with Postman and scan the QR code on my phone.

[image: Giltee_0-1689794542093.png]

Statically adding the the URL to an img tag works fine as well (although not what I need).

[image: Giltee_1-1689794638253.png]

How can I access the data in a liquid template like the products:

I want to do something similar to:

`{{ products.product.sold_out }}`
but with the qr code

`{{ products.product.qrcode.image }}`

Comment: you need to add the image in the product metafields.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please describe how you registered the app, does it have the stable url? I suppose you will need to create some kind of a controller that your store should call via js/img insert passing the product id, that will return the QR image.

Comment: The answer is already provided in the comment, this suggestion is actually incorrect and could mislead people.